# Rails POST Request Invalid Token Authority

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, authenticity-token

I have built a POST request route as:

```
match '/getActivatedFriends',
  to: 'requests#getActivatedFriends', via: 'post',
  constraints: { friends_phone_number_csv: /([0-9]+,?)+/ }
```

with action:

```
def getActivatedFriends
    @results = BusinessUser.find_by_sql("SELECT 
                                            a.id
                                         ,  a.username
                                         ,  a.phoneNumber
                                         FROM users a
                                         WHERE phoneNumber in ('+params[:friends_phone_number_csv]+') and
                                               removed = 0 and
                                               is_user = 1;")

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json { render json: { friends_match: @results }}
    end         
end
```

That should return a JSON object of the users that match. I have tested with POSTMAN as:

[image]

But what returns is the error noting invalid authenticity token

How can I reconfigure to make this POST route work?

Comment: can we see your routes

Comment: Running rake routes shows that it should exist: `getActivatedFriends POST   /getActivatedFriends(.:format)                                                  requests#getActivatedFriends`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default Rails uses [`CSRF protection`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) in controller. [It is add to your form `hidden_field` with authenticity token.](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html) But in your case you do not use form
you can disable [`CSRF protection`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) on controller by skipping the verification before_action.
Add to top of your requests controller:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```

or in `Rails 4 and 5`(it is the same command):

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

Comment: Why would this error appear for the POST request but not others?

Comment: Because it is `POST` request what should update some of your resources. It is make for  security reasons. IMO

Comment: Ok, I will simply need to secure later. Thank you, this worked

Comment: In rails 5 use *skip_before_action*